# why probability densities which take on infinities for certain $x$ can still have finite integrals

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I am trying to teach myself some calculus and statistics and I came across the idea of a probability density function which, as I understand, basically describes the probability per unit value of the random variable.

So it is analogous to densities we encounter in Physics and tells how much probability is concentrated near $x$ and to get the probability we have:

$$P(x) = f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

where $f(x)$ is the density function and $\mathrm{d}x$ is the differential.

Now, from laws of probability we have:

$$
\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 1
$$

The thing that I cannot get my head around is that this PDF can take on value of infinity for certain values of $x$ and still have a finite integral of $1$. How is that possible?

Comment: It is due to the definition $0\cdot \infty=0$. If the size of the set where they take the value $\infty$ is $0$, then those values contribute $0$ to the integral: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f=\int_{\{x:\ |f(x)|<\infty\}}f+\int_{\{x:\ f(x)=\infty\}}f=\int_{\{x:\ |f(x)|<\infty\}}f+\infty\cdot\mu(\{x:\ f(x)=\infty\})$.

Comment: @blueInk Thanks for the comment. So, these values do not contribute to the calculation of the probability in the neighbourhood of $x$ either, I guess? The reason I am having trouble is that if they are not contributing at all, would it not be possible to define these functions without these infinities?

Comment: Yes, if the set $\{x:\ f(x)=\infty\}$ has measure zero, then you can redefine the function there as anything you want without changing the distribution. Also the function is not going to be too large at the points in which it is finite. Remember that one still must have $\int_{\{x:\ |f(x)|<\infty\}}f=1$. Also, in your second sentence it sounds like you are thinking of $f$ as continuous. That can be the case, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @blueInk Thanks for this. It is a bit clearer to me know. I am self studying and do not know much about measure theory but I will look it up as to what it means for a set to have a measure zero. Thank you again.